# Add onclick event listener to transparent activity

Tags: android

I have transparent activity using transparent  theme :

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

and I want when this activity appears then the user clicked it, it finishs
the main xml file code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:onClick="hide">


</RelativeLayout>
```

and the code of main activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void hide(){
    finish();
}
```

but of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is missing the `param`. It should be

```
public void hide(View v){  // notice the parameter it takes for the onClick
    finish();
}
```

Notice the third requirement stated in the [Button Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

> The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:
>
> Be public
>
> Return void
>
> Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

Comment: After adding it, this works good but I wanted to know where is this layout located so I changed the background color of the relative layout to black and when I saw it, it was a small square at top*left corner of the widget area it self.
So how can I make the layout fits all the screen and transparent at the same time to allow people to finish the whole activity when they click on any part of that relative layout.
I hope it makes sense I found it hard to explain :)
thnx

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I do understand what you are doing

Comment: See this pic when I click the widget it shows me the little square how to make it full screen :)
http://s21.postimg.org/8zuwxyjyf/Untitled.png

Comment: Hmmm...this I am not sure about at the moment.

Comment: You know the trick is :
I want when the user clicks my widget two another imageViews appear next to my widget and when he clicks one of them pop up window will appear 
However I thought that the transparent activity will help me add these elements and hide them and then show them when the user clicks the widget.
and I wanted that if the user clicked on any other part of the screen other than my imageviews the activity finishes and the user gets back to the launcher again :)